# Questions on mongoDB query exact year

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am building a html form where it will query the MongoDB and retrieve the entire record based on the year.

How can I query only the year?

Something along the line in SQL:

```sql
select * from database where date == '2021'
```

How to do the equivalent in MongoDB?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are storing the dates as `Date` you have two options:

First one is to create dates and compare (not tested in python but should work):

```py
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2022,1,1)

db.find({date: {$gte: start, $lt: end}});
```

Note the trick here is to query dates between the desired year, like [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/anqp126Pr30)

The other way is using aggregation like this:

Here you are getting the year using `$year` and comparing with your desired value.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$eq": [
          {
            "$year": "$date"
          },
          2021
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BFmPom5iJ8y)